# VMWare, esxi, vsphere, bare-metal

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, bare-metal

I would like to run multiple desktops simultaneously on the esxi without having to connect from another computer via vsphere.

Can the be done straight on esxi? Or would I have to install workstation from an already installed OS?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ESXi is specifically headless.

You could install an OS that has support for acting as a type I hypervisor such as Windows 8/Server 2012+, linux with KVM or XenServer, or run software on top of the base OS to act as a type II hypervisor, such as VMware Workstation or VirtualBox.

If you do use VMware Workstation, you can connect to the virtual machines it's hosting via VSphere on another computer, if that's a requirement.